# how to tell the monotonicity of an implicit function?

Tags: convex-analysis, implicit-differentiation

I have a function $F(x,y)=0$. Taking derivative of this implicit function, i can get that $y'>0$ if $x>Cy$, and $y'\le 0$ if $x\le Cy$. $C$ is some constant. Can i say $y$ is concave in $x$?

Comment: What is $F(x,y)$ here, specifically?

Comment: $\frac{a}{x}-\frac{b}{x-y}+\frac{c}{d+y}=0$. $a,b,c,d$ are some constants

Comment: can you do a second derivative test for concavity?

Comment: I have tried, but failed.